# How do I concat a string + int and match it to an item in an NSArray?

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

Heres my Array.

```
NSArray *arrayData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1 days", @"7 days", 
    @"14 days", @"28 days", @"1 months", @"2 months", 
    @"3 months", @"4 months", @"6 months", @"1 years", 
    @"2 years", @"once", nil];
```

Heres my NSString and my integer.

```
int interval = 2;
NSString *itype = @"years";
```

I need to join both the integer + a space + the NSString and match it with the item in the array and get the index number of the array so I can pick the same index from another NSArray.

How do i do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To join the string and integer:

```
NSString* yearString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@", interval, itype];
```

And to search the array:

```
[array indexOfObject:yearString];
```

Comment: OK, so wheres the index number ?

Comment: int indexOfObject = [array indexOfObject:yearString]; //  :)